# how to run a mysql> type query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been sent this example of a mysql query to run, how can i run it in PHP?

```
mysql> CALL get_queue_report(0001, 4, 1393668000, 1394186399, @error); select @error
+----------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+--------------+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| total_answered | agent_terminated | caller_terminated | channel_incompat | transfered | abandoned | enteredq | timeout_exit | avg_calltime | avg_holdtime | avg_holdtime_abandon | avg_pos_abandon | avg_advance_abandon | avg_pos | joinunavail | leaveunavail | exitfull | exitkey | joinempty | leaveempty |
+----------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+--------------+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 0 | NULL | NULL | 2 | 1 | 0 | NULL | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+----------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------+-------------+--------------+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) I'd guess something like this (using mysqli):

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("CALL get_queue_report(0001, 4, 1393668000, 1394186399, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $return_value, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000); 
$stmt->execute();

print "procedure returned $return_value\n";
```

Comment: for some reason i cannot connect to the mysql database using PDO or MySQLi, so just for testing initially how can i use this code in MySQL ?

Comment: @user3223205 You should find out why, and fix it. ;) It is the best was to implement database connections currently. And if not **the best** then at least better than mysql.
Maybe afterwards this might come in handy then: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php#example-1639